# Create and align 2 html tables

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I want to create 2 tables with the opening hours of 2 shops. I would like them to align next to each other in the middle of the page when there is room for it. And otherwise, I want them to center align under each other? For some reason, this really isn't working. 
I'm using a Saas solution and I don't have access to the css files so I need to use inline css? 
Could someone help me with this?

```
    <div style="width: 100%; padding: 5%; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
<div style="padding: 2%;">
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Rotterdam</h3>
<table style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Maandag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">12:00 - 18:00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Dinsdag </td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">10:00 - 18:00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Woensdag </td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">10:00 - 18:00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Donderdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">10:00 - 18:00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Vrijdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">10:00 - 18:00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Zaterdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">10:00 - 17:30 </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px; text-align: left;">Zondag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px; text-align: left;">12:00 - 17:30</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="padding: 2%;">
<h3 style="text-align: center;">Capelle a/d IJssel</h3>
<table style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 13px; text-align: left; align: center;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 13px;">Maandag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 13px;">12:00 - 17:30</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Dinsdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">09:30 - 17:30</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Woensdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">09:30 - 17:30</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Donderdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">09:30 - 17:30</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Vrijdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">09:30 - 21:00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px; text-align: left;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">Zaterdag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px;">09:30 - 17:00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 15px;">
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px; text-align: left;">Zondag</td>
<td style="width: 50%; height: 15px; text-align: left;">Gesloten</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
    box-sizing: border-box;
```

to the main `div`: this is telling the browser to calculate the children width with the remaining width inside that div.

For the responsiveness you should use `media queries` to change the alignment

Comment: Any suggestions on the media queries? And is this something I can do inline?

Comment: actually no, you have to use style tag in the header or a .css file